# Excel IF / AND Condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two formulas in an Excel file and I want to merge them in one cell:

```
=IF(AND(D2="VSE",G2>=100%),F2*0.65%)
=IF(AND(D2="VSE",H2<=18000),H2,"18000")
```

to calculate incentive.

Our VSE have Budget X and Achievement Y and %Achievement z
if VSE achieve 100% and above, than calculate Amount Like Achievement*0.65%, if amount is more than 18000 then display only 18000 in same cell.

Comment: 18000 in the second `IF` is number, if you enclose it into `"`, you are telling Excel it's string (text) and it will be treated like it. It may leads in weird future errors! Do not use `"` if you work with numbers!

Comment: Try to provide a simple sample and your conditions are not very clearly. G2>=100% and H2<=18000, they are 2 contradictory conditions.

Comment: (1) Please try to make your question clearer.  Your paragraph says “X”, “Y”, and “z”, but your code uses `D`, `F`, `G`, and `H`.  Be consistent.  (2) I have edited your question to include a table you can use to show desired results for various inputs.  Please fill it out.  Replace the ?s with values and the ???s with explanations.  (3) Look at the `MIN()` function — it may simplify your life. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas in Excela could be nested.

`IF` formula has three arguments ([see help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)) Condition, Value when True, value when False. Value could be another expression.

Like:
`IF(A1=1, "A1 is 1", A1*2)` - This formula returns string `"A1 is 1"` when value in `A1` is equal to `1` or value of `A1` multiplied by 2.

Analogically, you can chain `IF` formula:
`IF(A1=1,"A1 is 1",IF(A1=2,"A1 is 2","A1 is other"))`

etc...

//update:

If I understand it correctly.

```
H2=IF(AND(D2="VSE",G2>=100%),F2*0.65%)
I2=IF(AND(D2="VSE",H2<=18000),H2,"18000")
```

Decision process:

1. Check if `D2="VSE"`. If true GOTO `2`, else GOTO`6`
2. Check if `G2>100%`. If true GOTO `3`, else GOTO `6`
3. Check if `F2*0.65%<=18000`. If true GOTO `4`, else GOTO `5`
4. Return result of `F2*0.65%`
5. Return `18000`
6. Return nothing (`""`)

Formula builded from above:

```
=IF(D2="VSE",IF(G2>100%,IF(F2*0.65%<=18000,F2*0.65%,18000),""),"")
```

Comment: You can nest IF statements using the AND function as in the question so you answer does not answer nor help the question being asked.